# Ionic Android Build Failed

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-build, hybrid-mobile-app

I am starting out in hybrid development and I chose cordova and ionic to start off. I am following the ionic documentation. However after creating a new ionic project and adding android as a platform, I repeatedly fail while trying to build the android platform. I've been trying to solve this problem for days now. Kindly help so that i can move forward with some actual development.

```
    BUILD FAILED
    C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:973: The following error occurred whi
le executing this line:
C:\android-sdk-windows\tools\ant\build.xml:312: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCrea
tionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\todo\platforms\android\ant-buil
d\classes.dex does not exist
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:469)
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.<init>(ApkBuilder.java:394)
        at com.android.ant.ApkBuilderTask.execute(ApkBuilderTask.java:334)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.jav
a:396)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at com.android.ant.IfElseTask.execute(IfElseTask.java:124)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Sequential.execute(Sequential.java:68)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.MacroInstance.execute(MacroInstance.jav
a:396)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.jav
a:106)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExe
cutor.java:41)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\todo\platforms\android\ant-build\cl
asses.dex does not exist
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.checkInputFile(ApkBuilder.java:93
8)
        at com.android.sdklib.build.ApkBuilder.init(ApkBuilder.java:440)
        ... 62 more

Total time: 25 seconds

C:\todo\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "ant debug -f C:\todo\platforms\a
ndroid\build.xml -Dout.dir=ant-build -Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen"
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error: C:\todo\platforms\android\cordova\bu
ild.bat: Command failed with exit code 8
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: C:\todo\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat: Command failed with exit cod
e 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\com\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cord
ova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\superspawn.js:131:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

Comment: what java version you are using ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was finally able to solve it by going into `C:\todo\platforms\android\ant-build` folder where `todo` is the name of the ionic project i created and rename the `classes.dex.d` file to `classes.dex`

Answer (score 2):

In general cordova, i might had tried to remove the platform and re-add it using the command line.

```
cordova platform rm android

cordova platform add android
```

But, I'm glad you found a fix.

Answer (score 1):

Glad you were able to figure it out! The easiest way i have found to do ionic android and ios builds is through intel xdk. If you have a ionic project already you can import it as an intel project, it has a built in device emulator and build server. Just hit build and it automates the process. It also handles all of the config files for you and gives you a nice ui for editing them. https://software.intel.com/en-us/html5/tools

Answer (score 0):

To solve the Issue make sure Android SDK installed successfully,If yes

1) Go back from cordova project directory (cd..)
2) Then get into the cordova project directory and use "cordova platform add android  --save --fetch" for fetching 
3) If no error comes up then try to Remove the platform and add again

It works for me